# Best way to transfer audio stream wia wlan

Tags: android, audio, tcp, udp, wifi

I want to implement a VOIP app in android phone and there's something difficult when transfer the audio data for me. I gather audio raw data with 8000HZ, then compress the audio stream with Speex and to cause about 20kb/s stream size. I buffer audio stream then send/receive via TCP. Because UDP package in 3G phone network may be ignored by several routers. I also write an media proxy server to transfer audio stream. This sever is in the public network. But it will cause the serious delay and slow speed. The server I rented has the speed of 4Mb/s. I don't know whether the server speed can satisfy my requirement. Can you please help me to resolve this real time crucial problem? Or give me an direction for improving the system efficient? Thanks very much.

Comment: are you sure the issue is in network and not in on the fly encoding & compressing?

Comment: I'm not sure but, the send/receive rate on one phone is about 1.5 : 1. And can you give me any idea for how can I position the problems? Thanks very much.